# R: Is there a way to get a a(b-c) notation when I have the values a,b,c in separated columns?

Tags: r, excel

I have calculated intraclass correlations for certain variables. 
There are three important values I want to display in a table:

- Variable name
- ICC value
- Lower bound
- Upper bound

I now made a table in R with the 4 columns next to each other

```
Name    ICCvalue     Lower bound    Upperbound   
a        0.90           0.46          0.98
```

However, for my scientific paper I want to use the following notation

```
Name    ICCvalue (Lowerbound-Upperbound)   
a       0.90 (0.46 - 0.98)
```

Is there a way to export my data in this way from R to excel? Otherwise I have to copy paste all values to achieve this result.

Comment: The key point to understand (implicit in all the answers) is that you want to create a _string_ (or _character_ in R lingua) from your 3 numeric values. The easiest / most intuitive way to create strings is with `paste` (see `?paste`), but there's also `sprintf`, the `glue` package, etc. You can then use `write.csv` to create a csv file and load it in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

In R:

```
df[, "(Lowerbound - Upperbound)"] = sprintf("(%s - %s)", df[, "Lower bound"], df[, "Upperbound"])
```

I'd also encourage you to be consistent about whether or not you use a space in "lowerbound". I copied the column names in your question, one of which has a spacec, and one of which doesn't.

Comment: The typo in lowerbound was just because I typed this text to be able to ask my question. Normally these names are outputted from the icc function directly. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```
within(df, `(Lowerbound-Upperbound)` <- paste("(", Lower bound , "-", Upperbound, ")", sep=''))

# Name ICCvalue Lowerbound Upperbound (Lowerbound-Upperbound)
# 1    a      0.9       0.46       0.98            (0.46-0.98)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tidyverse way:

```r
library(writexl)
library(tidyverse)

data <- tribble(
  ~Name, ~ICCvalue, ~`Lower bound`, ~Upperbound,   
  "a",   0.90,      0.46,           0.98  
)

(new_data <- data %>% transmute(
  Name, 
  `ICCvalue (Lowerbound-Upperbound)` = 
    str_glue_data(., "{ICCvalue} ({`Lower bound`} - {Upperbound})")
))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   Name  `ICCvalue (Lowerbound-Upperbound)`
#>   <chr> <glue>                            
#> 1 a     0.9 (0.46 - 0.98)

write_xlsx(new_data, "result.xlsx")
```

The `` "{ICCvalue} ({`Lower bound`} - {Upperbound})" `` is the most concise expression of what you want the values to be, right? The `glue` functions utilize such expressions, with the bracketed values to be referenced by name and inserted. The only tricky part here is that the value objects being referenced are vectors of values - whole columns - so you have to use `str_glue_data()`, with the first argument being the list, environment, etc. that the referenced vectors are inside. The `.` here is actually `data`, since that's the object being piped in to the whole `transmute()` call.

`transmute()`, as you can see, just makes a new table out of `data` with just the columns I've named or defined. Namely, this drops the original columns we no longer need.

Also included the code to output the result to Excel.

Another tidy way would be to use `tidyr::unite()`, but you'd need to use it separately a couple times, with different separators, and then add the right parenthesis separately anyway, so...

<sup>Created on 2019-10-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, I understand :) I will see if I can get it working in my code